# How frequently should I rebuild my App Engine search index (full text search)?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, full-text-search, gae-search

It seems like—at least for now—I have to manually keep the search index in sync with the datastore.  If I rebuild the index every time something is changed in the datastore, I assume I will run into quota issues, so I figured it would be better to create a cron job to rebuild the index regularly.  How frequently should I rebuild the index to avoid running into quota issues?

Comment: how is your data structured? what do you store in the search index? how do you store it in the index? are you using python/java? if python are you using `db` or `ndb`? there is a lot more info needed. and if you have to recreate your search index completely on every change you are doing something wrong...

Comment: Sorry, I guess I do not have a good understanding of how the full text search API works.  It is a Python app.  I am using `db` and HRD.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: and what do you store in the search api? i highly suggest you to start using `ndb` instead of `db` in any case. it has a lot of good parts `db` is missing.

Comment: I store titles, descriptions, types, and categories of items to be searched.  I can look into using `ndb`.  Does it offer anything that would help with search, or is it just a good idea in general?

Comment: in general. check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ndb` for you Models where you have [Model Hooks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks) to index entities after putting them with a `_post_put_hook`.

for example:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()

    def _post_put_hook(self, future):
        fields = [search.TextField(name='title', value=self.title)]
        doc    = search.Document(doc_id=self.key.id(), fields=fields)
        search.Index('index-name').put(doc)
        ...
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__post_put_hook

Comment: So, to be clear, that will automatically update the datastore item's respective search index entry whenever the datastore item is updated?

Comment: yes if you use a unique identifier as the search documents key. so everytime you update an entity it will overwrite the searchdoc with that specific doc_id.

Comment: and of course you should remove the search doc when you delete the entity. obviously with a `_post_delete_hook`